# Publishing in facebook page as admin in v2.3 Javascript api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to post in fan page as admin but it does not work:

it works but not as admin

```
 var wallPost = {
                            access_token: token,
                            message: 'asdasdasd'
                        };
                        FB.api('/xxxxx/feed', 'post', wallPost, function(response) {
                           console.log(response);
                        });
```

This has an error:

```
                    FB.api('/' + page_id, {fields: 'access_token'}, function(resp) {
                        if(resp.access_token) {
                            FB.api('/' + page_id + '/feed',
                                'post',
                                { message: "I'm a Page!", access_token: resp.access_token }
                                ,function(response) {
                                    console.log(response);
                            });
                        }else{
                             console.log(resp);
                        }
                    });
```

the error is:
"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

My scope: 'manage_pages,publish_actions,read_stream,user_groups'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v2.3, you need permission [`publish_pages`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-publish_pages) (in addition to `manage_pages`) to post as a page.

They separated this from `publish_actions`, which is now for posting as a user only.

(See also: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_changes)